# How to disable stretching for camera preview?

Tags: android, mobile, camera, android-camera

When I set my SurfaceView as target surface for my camera preview(as in [and-dev tutorial](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera) for camera API 1) it will stretching picture from camera as far as needed for filling whole surface with that picture. How I can disable that? I want to have 2 black strips for areas with no appropriate image data from camera rather then scaled image over all surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom view with an inner SurfaceView

as @momo reports in his solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21653728/2124387):

```
public class CroppedCameraPreview extends ViewGroup {
  private SurfaceView cameraPreview;
  public CroppedCameraPreview( Context context ) {
    super( context );
    // i'd probably create and add the SurfaceView here, but it doesn't matter
  }
  @Override
  protected void onMeasure( int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec ) {
    setMeasuredDimension( croppedWidth, croppedHeight );
  }
  @Override
  protected void onLayout( boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b ) {
    if ( cameraPreview != null ) {
      cameraPreview.layout( 0, 0, actualPreviewWidth, actualPreviewHeight );
    }
  }
}
```