# Camera draws outside the view

Tags: android

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21653728/476074) technique to crop the camera preview.

The problem is that I do it in a dialog and the camera preview is also drawn outside of the bounds of the dialog:

[image: Screenshot]

What can I do?

Comment: try overriding `onDraw` and calling `canvas.clipRect`.  might also want to try a `TextureView` instead of a `SurfaceView`

Comment: I think https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/EMBEDDING.md is describing the same problem.