# Camera Preview Customize for capture image in square box or circle

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, surfaceview, android-camera2

[Is it possible to crop camera preview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601982/is-it-possible-to-crop-camera-preview)
Actually I am looking for Customize Android phone camera preview I just want to show fix size box or selectable box(like image cropping but this will be Camera preview cropping).

According to stack overflow answer it is not possible using camera Api but it is possible with Surface view or using camera 2 api.
please suggest any Idea
Thanks

Comment: As described in the linked discussion, you can show an overlay with transparent "hole" of any size and shape on top of the live camera preview, effectively cropping it.

Comment: any source code please help me