# Crop camera preview

Tags: android, crop, preview, stretched

I want to run android camera preview with a 640x480 resolution but display just 480x360. Right now I'm getting a stretched preview, even though I've tried to put the surface view in a frame layout or srollview. Can anyone tell me how this can be done?
A similar question has been asked before: [How to crop camera preview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593100/how-to-crop-camera-preview), but nobody answered.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using TextureView for camera preview. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html.

> Unlike SurfaceView, TextureView does not create a separate window but behaves as  a regular View. This key difference allows a TextureView to be moved, transformed, animated, etc. For instance, you can make a TextureView semi-translucent by calling myView.setAlpha(0.5f).